# No serializer found for class java.io.BufferedReader

Tags: json, spring-mvc, java-io

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.BufferedReader and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: pj.core.bean.ActionResult["data"]->pj.core.bean.ActionList["list"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap["role"]->net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl["characterStream"])

How can i solve this problem....

Comment: Err, don't try to serialize `BufferedReaders`? It doesn't make any sense anyway.

Comment: I can't fix java.io.BufferedReader....

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the object you try to serialize to json? It seems like the object (or some object in your object graph) contains a BufferedReader field. is this correct?

You might want to annotate this field (or getter-method) with @JsonIgnore to make jackson ignore it or add this annotation to the part of your object graph that contains the BufferedReader.

Please let me know how this workes out if you give it a try. Good luck!

:)